# In Jsp how to add empty option before populating db values in dropdwon

Tags: jsp

I am iterating over a session attribute and populating my dropdown. Before that i need an Empty option insde my dropwdown. I have tried the follwing piece of code,

```
<select id="releaseValue" name="releaseValue"
        style="width: 180px;" required class="chosen-select-width validate">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
            <c:forEach var="release" items="${release}">
               <option><c:out value="${release}"/></option>
            </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But it is not adding the empty option into my dropdwon. Need your suggesstion

Comment: so you want selected in first right?

Comment: can you post the output HTML (just the select portion) after it was rendered to your browser?

Comment: @Ish the db values gets added in the output html except the empty option

Comment: your code should work

Comment: I actually don't see anything wrong with the structure of your select and option elements. Unless I see the actual HTML code generated, perhaps we can see something like malformed structure preventing the first option not to appear. Perhaps, this is a browser compatibility thing, but I highly doubt it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty value on your controller
like this:

```
List<abc> list = new ArrayList<abc>();
list.add(0,"");
```

Comment: This should be a comment